# How to list fields of a node and dump it's data? GraphQL introspection

Tags: graphql, introspection

I was able to get the `username`s like this:

```
query {
  allUsers {
    edges {
      node {
        username
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But when I tried the same for the `xxx` node like this:

```
query {
  allUsers {
    edges {
      node {
        xxx
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It says:

> Field "xxx" of type "NoteObjectConnection" must have a sub
> selection.

How can I read the data in `xxx` node?

Comment: `xxx` seems to be a non scalar, therefore you need something like `xxx { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

In GraphQL, every field must resolve to concrete data (like `Int`, `Float`, `String`, etc.). The error is pretty straightforward; you need to select fields on `xxx`:

```
query {
  allUsers {
    edges {
      node {
        xxx {
          other
          fields
          needed
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```